# How to embed background picture into Excel report in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I'm trying to embed a background picture into an Excel file. Assuming I have an Excel report (see f.csv) below, I open it as an Excel, embed the picture and then save.

I found the following code in one of the websites. It's working but still there is a problem that it always ask me to confirm the overwriting of the file. I want to save it automatically without asking the user about it, but can't find if that's possible. See below I tried "SaveAs" and "Save" but it always ask me to confirm overwriting.

Please see the code and let me know if that possible. Thanks in advance!

```
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\f.csv")
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("f")

        'set back ground
        xlWorkSheet.SetBackgroundPicture("C:\rnd-draft.png")

          xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\f.csv")
      '  xlWorkBook.Save()

        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is how it is done in excel VBA. I am not sure whether this can be manipulated with vb.net

```
Sub Macro1()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'supress all alerts in excel
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "C:\f.csv"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'enables alerts
End Sub
```

This code usually overwrites the file without any prompt. An issue occurs if the file is in use.